# Where are files of saved games of Capitalism II

Tags: windows-7, capitalism-2

I bought Capitalism II on gog.com and began tutorials. I saved them and I want to back-up those file in my Dropbox directory. Where are they?

I searched them on my hard drive withthe name that I use in game but I didn't find them.

I bought also `Theme Hospital` from gog.com and I found my saved game in

`C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\GOG.com\Theme Hospital\SAVE`

There's no other directory in

`C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\GOG.com\`

I looked also in `C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG.com\Capitalism 2\save` but the directory is empty. I saved at least 3 games...

Where are files of saved games of `Capitalism II`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found them.

First, the software saves files with the chief name that you gave when you begin a game. It asks you to enter a description. I thought it was the file name... The file name seems to be built with the 4 first characters (padded with underscores if the name is shorter than 4 characters) of the chief name followed by an underscore and an incremental number. The number begins at 001...

Finally, the files are located into 
`C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\Documents\My Games\Capitalism 2\SAVE`